# Python error "Unable to read URL" even though "Requirement already satisfied" in command prompt

Tags: python, yahoo-api

I've been trying to work on some beginner/entry level python projects for a resume (working with WIN10) and I've been running into the same constant error. I've been trying to pull info from yahoo finance and I get this error, no matter how I rework my code:

```
import pandas_datareader as web
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import datetime as dt

start = dt.datetime(2018,1,1)
end = dt.datetime.now()

tickers = ["FB", "GS", "NVDA", "MSFT", "TSLA", "AAPL", "CCL", "BA"]
colnames = []

for ticker in tickers:
  data = web.DataReader(ticker, "yahoo", start, end)
  if len(colnames) == 0:
    combined = data[['Adj Close']].copy()
  else:
    combined = combined.join(data['Adj Close'])
    colnames.append(ticker)
    combined.columns = colnames

  print(combined)

RemoteDataError: Unable to read URL: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/FB/history?period1=1514779200&period2=1652673599&interval=1d&frequency=1d&filter=history
```

I looked around and saw that yahoo finance changed it's structure for python, so I then tried changing the format or my code, still got the error. I tried installing suggested libraries to fix it, and while it says that their installed, I can't use the libraries because it says that module isn't found.

I've looked at other Stack posts and none of the solutions are helping.

Comment: Your code worked for me... Are you using a virtual environment? https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Comment: I've been bouncing back and forth between Jupyter notebook and colaboratory. Should I start using something else?

Comment: In Python generally it's best practice not to install packages to your general environment but to create a virtual environment, activate that environment, and then install what python packages you need to use. Then when you create another project you can create a new environment for that project and installing new packages won't affect your existing installations. This will make it easier to uninstall/install packages for each project without any unexpected behavior from clashing verisons. https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/#why-do-you-need-virtual-environments

Comment: I'm sorry for potentially a very stupid question, but I'm still new to all of this. What would you recommend as a virtual environment and should I go and uninstall some/all of my packages? If not, what would you recommend? Thank you for your patience.

Comment: you can create a virtual environment from command line by typing python3 -m venv name_of_env then by entering source name_of_env/bin/activate you activate the environment, and now when running python while the environment is activated you can install whatever you want (nothing will be installed by default besides python). If you type deactivate you will be back in your global environment, with whatever packages you have installed globally. I don't use Jupyter but here is a link that explains how to use a virtual env with juypter https://janakiev.com/blog/jupyter-virtual-envs/